# Как собрать проект Java FX?

Tags: java, javafx, maven, ant

Написал приложение на Java FX. С Использованием дополнительных библиотек (Hibernate, Jfoenix и др). Как нужно собрать проект чтобы получить готовую программу которую можно использовать на других ПК. Пробывал использовать artifact но .jar файл не запускается. Слышал нужно использовать maven или ant но ничего нормального не нашёл.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сразу оговорюсь, что речь будет идти о IDE Eclipse. Чтобы собрать JavaFX проект вам нужно понять, как создать executable JAR (существуют еще runnable JAR для запуска консольных программ). Почитать о разнице можете [здесь](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-JAR-and-a-runnable-JAR-in-Eclipse) и [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4974693/java-eclipse-difference-between-exporting-as-a-jar-and-exporting-as-a-runnable). Также советую посмотреть краткий [видеоурок](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7PlcK_lu0aY) (в данном случае не используются Ant или Maven), чтобы быстрее понять принцип создания самого executable JAR. И обратите внимание, что добавляется **manifest** файл! Зачем? Тут вам ответит официальная документация от [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/manifestindex.html).

Далее, если вы все же хотите совершить сборку с помощью Maven, то для этого нужно создать отдельный Maven-проект - о чем вы можете почитать [здесь](https://devcolibri.com/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-jar-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%B2-maven/) и [здесь](http://www.baeldung.com/executable-jar-with-maven). Также есть отличная информация на английском stackoverflow, советую ознакомиться с [ней](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574594/how-can-i-create-an-executable-jar-with-dependencies-using-maven).

Надеюсь, этот ответ вам тоже поможет. :)

Answer (score 0):

Если в intellij IDEA -

1. Project settings - вкладка слева Artifacts , в ней :

`Output directory - указываем путь куда создастся проект
 вкладка Output Layout - перетаскиваем на лево все что нужно
                 - вкладка JavaFx - Application class - шелкай справа 3 точки - и выбирай main class 
                 - на этой же вкладке Native bundle - all`

2. Build - Build artifacts - имя артифакта - build

Comment: Создался каталог с jar файлами библиотек и JNLP файл похожий на exe. При запуске ошибка - application blocked by java security

Comment: @markTitan, а вы случайно не работатли как раз с java.security? 
Возможно так же из-за многопоточки(вроде) может вызваться такая ошибка. 

Но как решать пока не знаю.